# External stylesheet properties not reflecting on HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have made a style sheet and have tried to place it inside the head tags of my .html file, but the style is not executing. What am I missing?

Here is my style sheet, saved as `myStyle.css`:

```
body {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333333;
}

p {
    font-size: medium;
}

h1 {
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

and here is my HTML code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Something Something</h1>
        <p>Launching in the Summer 2016</p>
        <p>ipsum loren il advica en tu tucci el ario</p>

        <div id="slideshow">
            <div>
                <img src="...\354\Images\trovi.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <p></p>
        DIGIT Game Studios
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems like it would work. Does it partially work or does it not work at all?

Comment: The bog standard black and white html page still loads... just no css executing

Comment: Make sure the file name is correct (with capital S) and make sure the css file is in the same folder as the html. Also check the console in your browser for any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. The problem is with your link to the CSS. What is your directory structure?

Comment: I have a sub folder for the css file

Comment: You did not include that subfolder in the link above. Include it, and your CSS will work.

Comment: so the code works, thats cool, must be how i have them stored

Comment: It's how you have it linked. For example, if your CSS is in a folder called css, change your link to this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyle.css"/>`

Comment: yep, that was exactly it... cheers red sauce, much appreciated! no more banging my head of the table!

Comment: Haha perfect. Glad you got it figured out! Welcome to Stack Overflow.